# How can i show the htmltext in XtraGrid column in devexpress

Tags: devexpress

I am having the Xtragrid showing the datatable details. In the datatable I am having html text in one column. I want to show html Text for that column. Any one please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the column's `ColumnEdit` property to an instance of the [`RepositoryItemRichTextEdit` class](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemRichTextEdittopic). Set the `RepositoryItemRichTextEdit.DocumentFormat` property to [`DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.DocumentFormat.Html`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressXtraRichEditDocumentFormattopic).

This should allow you to achieve the required behavior.

Comment: You have to include the references to `DevExpress.XtraRichEdit` and `DevExpress.RichEdit.Core`.

Comment: For the later .Net 6 versions you should add references to `DevExpress.Win.RichEdit` and `DevExpress.RichEdit.Core`.